# Post form within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to achieve is similar to how the links that are clicked within the div load only within the div but instead with forms so any forms posted within the div are loaded within the div.

So for example if I have a form inside the `#profile-body`;

```
<form method="POST" action="/post.php">
<input name="test" type="text"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

when the form has been submitted the action page is loaded within the div.

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.profile-body, #profile-body a',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();// prevent browser from opening url
         $('#profile-body').load(this.href);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    var defaultPage = "defaultpage.html";
    $('#profile-body').load(defaultPage);
});

<div id="profile-body"></div>
```

My question is how would I get the form posted page to be loaded in the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load()` can use POST method if some object data is passed. So you should try something like that:

```
$('div > form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent('div').load(this.action, $(this).serializeArray());
});
```

Comment: I tried the code that you posted but it doesn't work. still loads the form outside of the div. hmm

Comment: Sorry but i have no idea what means "doesn't work" nor what what you have tried...? Can you post an MCVE? Maybe you need to delegate event but again your question is quite missing context to make it clearer

Comment: do i need to change the above code in any way for it to work?, the form is still get posted to the whole page instead of just within the div.

Comment: If so, that's means the default behaviour isn't prevented. Again, maybe you just need to delegate it, e.g: `$(document).on('submit', 'div > form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent('div').load(this.action, $(this).serializeArray());
});`. But still, without seeing any concrete example of what you are looking for, i can just guessing